# Symfony Doctrine - Joins without foreign keys

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to set up a schema to capture twitter users and their followers.

I have two tables. TwitterUser and Follower. Follower has 3 fields - id, twitterUser, follower.

When a twitter user is a added to the table, I also add a row to Followers to join them with other users I may be interested in.

However, If I get Symfony/Doctrine to build the tables using something like the following-

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="follower")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Follower
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TwitterUser", inversedBy="followers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $twitterUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TwitterUser", inversedBy="following")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="follower_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $follower;
...
```

It insists on creating a Foreign Key for `follower` that I don't want, as I don't want to have to get ALL twitter users to ensure that my joins always work.

The only way I can think to do it, is to remove the annotation and create the SQL for the join myself. Is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a ManyToMany self-referencing relationship as describe below:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: Yes, I've tried self referencing, but foreign keys are still generated. From the example - `ALTER TABLE friends ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
ALTER TABLE friends ADD FOREIGN KEY (friend_user_id) REFERENCES User(id);`